# How to Call a Jbutton(Swing) from a Jsp page (Web)?

Tags: java, swing, jsp, servlets, java-web-start

As per My project Requirement I have to print a ticket when i click buy button on jsp page..one Desktop application already installed in client machine.I have to call the desktop application to print and pass the data from jsp to desktop application.

Comment: not. I don't know whether anyone ever told you this, but jsp's run server side,not client side.

Answer (score 4):

If a web page could reach outside the browser environment to 'click a button' it would be a major security risk. The specification is dangerous and not possible to implement.

So the answer to your question is - it is impossible.

Comment: Impossible is not possible. Implement server in swing. When user press button on jsp submit form to serverside, let serverside connect and send message to swing server running on user ip, do something in swing.

Comment: @TinusTate *"Impossible is not possible."* Code speaks louder than words. Enter your **code solution** as an answer.